# OpenCart search function isn't working correctly

Tags: opencart

I'm having some problems with the search function in OpenCart 1.5.4. Today, I added a product with meta tags, keywords, attributes, etc. All of the things I filled in could be searched for. So if I had a product called "A", with a keyword of "B" I could search for B and get product A as a search result.

However, I just added a new product with its own meta tags, keywords, attributes and so on, but now the search isn't working correctly anymore. I can only search for the product name, if I search on a keyword or tag, nothing is shown and I get the result that no products could be found.

I have deleted these two products, so there are no products now. I've added a new product, but still I can only search for its name. What is happening here?

Comment: Someone? It's really important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default search patterns on opencart are quite restrictive and they require that you use the same case. So if you search for a product with a tag of "Gold" howeve the search script will switch the case of all your searches on tags to lower case. I agree this is quite irritating and I am trying to build a workaround myself to ignore the case.

The problem stems to the model where the search is being performed LCASE is used during the MATCH MySQL command, this means it will not find any mixed case tags etc.

Hope that helps

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I too am looking for a way to include matched in the tag and description products in a users's search results.